# Correction importing excel in spring boot

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, google-sheets, import

I have tried this code to import an excel but it doesn't work. It always make the same error

**Repository**

```
public interface AjustageRepository extends JpaRepository<Ajustage, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT v FROM Ajustage v WHERE v.date = (SELECT MAX(v2.date) FROM Ajustage v2)")
    Ajustage lastInput();
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class ExcelService {

    @Autowired
    private AjustageRepository repository;

    public void processExcelFile(MultipartFile file) {
        try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file.getInputStream())) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1); // Deuxième feuille (index 1)
            int i = 0;
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                i++;
                if(i>1) {
                    Ajustage ajustage = new Ajustage();
                    if (row.getCell(0) != null && row.getCell(0).getCellType() != CellType.BLANK) 
                        break;
                    ajustage.setDate(row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());
                    ajustage.setLib(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                    ajustage.setCompte(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                    ajustage.setNombre(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue()).longValue());
                    ajustage.setDebit(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()).longValue());
                    ajustage.setCredit(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue()).longValue());
                    System.out.println(ajustage.toString());
                    repository.save(ajustage);
                    // Parcours des lignes de la deuxième feuille
                    // Insérer les données dans la base de données ici
                    // Vous pouvez accéder aux cellules de chaque ligne en utilisant row.getCell(cellIndex)
                    // Exemple d'insertion d'une donnée factice dans la base de données
                    //ExcelData excelData = new ExcelData();
                    //excelData.setData("Donnée insérée depuis le fichier Excel");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Gérer les erreurs de lecture du fichier Excel
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public void insertNewRecord(MultipartFile file) {
        try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file.getInputStream())) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1); // Deuxième feuille (index 1)
            int lastRowNum = this.lastRowNum(sheet);
            Ajustage last = repository.lastInput();
            
            Row row = sheet.getRow(lastRowNum);
            if(last != null) {
                Date toInsert = row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue();
                while(toInsert.after(last.getDate())) {
                    Ajustage ajustage = new Ajustage();
                    ajustage.setDate(row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());
                    ajustage.setLib(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                    ajustage.setCompte(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                    ajustage.setNombre(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue()).longValue());
                    ajustage.setDebit(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()).longValue());
                    ajustage.setCredit(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue()).longValue());
                    System.out.println(ajustage.toString());
                    repository.save(ajustage);
                    
                    //iteration boucle
                    lastRowNum--;
                    row = sheet.getRow(lastRowNum);
                    toInsert = row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue();
                }
            }
            else {
                while(lastRowNum > 0) {
                    Ajustage ajustage = new Ajustage();
                    ajustage.setDate(row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue());
                    ajustage.setLib(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                    ajustage.setCompte(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                    ajustage.setNombre(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue()).longValue());
                    ajustage.setDebit(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()).longValue());
                    ajustage.setCredit(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue()).longValue());
                    System.out.println(ajustage.toString());
                    repository.save(ajustage);
                    
                    //iteration boucle
                    lastRowNum--;
                    row = sheet.getRow(lastRowNum);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Gérer les erreurs de lecture du fichier Excel
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public int lastRowNum(Sheet sheet) {
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        for(int rowNum = lastRowNum; rowNum >= 0; rowNum--) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
            if (row != null && row.getCell(0) != null && row.getCell(0).getCellType() != CellType.BLANK) 
                return rowNum;
        }   
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This is the code for the controller

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/excel")
public class ExcelController {
    private final ExcelService excelService;

    @Autowired
    public ExcelController(ExcelService excelService) {
        this.excelService = excelService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/test") 
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Fichier Excel traité avec succès");
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadExcelFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("OKK##########");
        try {
            excelService.processExcelFile(file); // Appel de la méthode pour traiter le fichier Excel
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Fichier Excel traité avec succès");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Erreur lors du traitement du fichier Excel");
        }
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/version2")
    public ResponseEntity<String> insertNew(@RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("OKK##########");
        try {
            excelService.insertNewRecord(file); // Appel de la méthode pour traiter le fichier Excel
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Fichier Excel traité avec succès");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Erreur lors du traitement du fichier Excel");
        }
    }
}
```

This code import an axcel to a databse sql server via spring boot, So, i want to connect spring boot to sql server management studio, to practice crud operations, however when I try it i get an error: enter image description here So, I have added the dependencies: enter image description here I have added properties: enter image description here ... So, i want to connect spring boot to sql server management studio, to practice crud operations, however when I try it i get an error: enter image description here So, I have added the dependencies: enter image description here I have added properties: enter image description here ...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (And you even failed at uploading the images...)

Answer (score 0):

**AchatMci**

```
package com.sg.CompMO.model.mci;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="AchatMci")

public class AchatMci {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String agence;
    private String compte;
    private String code_ope;
    private String ecomm_code_ope;
    private Date date;
    //private Long nbDnweb;
    //private Long montantDnweb;
    private Long nb_mci_outgoing;
    private Long montant_mci_outgoing;
    private Long nb_sms;
    private Long montant_sms;
    private Long nb_rejets;
    private Long montant_rejets;
    private Long nbdeltacop;
    private Long montantdeltacop;
    private Long nbbkmvthcop;
    private Long montantbkmvthcop;
    private Long nbdeltaecom;
    private Long montantdeltaecom;
    //private Long nbajustagemci;
    //private Long montantajustagemci;
    private Long nbcouverturemci;
    private Long montantcouverturemci;
    //private Long nbecartDN;
    //private Long montantDN;
    private Long nbPost;
    private Long montantPost;
    private Long nb_couverturedelta;
    private Long montant_couverturedelta;
    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String obs;
    private String etat;
}
```

**CompensationMci**

```
package com.sg.CompMO.model.mci;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="CompensationMci")

public class CompensationMci {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String agence;
    private String compte;
    private String code_ope;
    private Date date;
    private Long couverturemci;
    private Long couverturehps;
    private Long fisDnweb;
    private Long bkmvtiFis;
    private Long BkmvthHps;
    private Long deltaCop;
    private Long BkmvthVSdelta;
    private Long dailyExtractjmoins1;
    private Long dailyExtractjplus1;
    private Long couvertureMcijustif;
    private Long autoverif;
    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String obs;
    
}
```